# Firefox Style tab - where has it gone?

Tags: firebug, firefox-developer-tools

It was simple in the old Firebug but it isn't there anymore and I can't get it back?
I'm sure it is simple, but where is it please?

To clarify, on the right side of the menu tabs in Firebug there was a *Style* tab and when you clicked it you could see the CSS changes for the :hover, :active, and :focus states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [Firebug is history](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/). What you are seeing are the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools).

In those tools the panel containing the CSS rules of the selected element is called *Rules*. And the options to toggle the :hover, :active and :focus states are available behind a button on the right side of the panel:

[image: State option panel inside *Rules* panel]

This and other questions are answered in the [migration guide for Firebug users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug).